# How to grant all object read access to windows user group

Tags: sql-server

I have almost 20+ Databases each db contains lot of procedure trigger view etc, also have development windows user group, i have to give view and execute privilege to the group members. Also read,write,update,delete privilege to tables. How i can give all together ?

I am using SQL 2012

Comment: Have you considered using database roles and adding the users to the role? If these users are part of an AD group that enables them to authenticate to SQL Server, then (in fact) you only need to add the AD group user to the role.

Comment: I am using AD Group, I want grant db view access (Tables -- Read, Write, update, delete, other objects -- View, Execute)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "view"? See the object definition?

Answer (score 2):

At a pure guess, and **assuming** the AD group already has a user on the database. You'll need to replace parts in the braces (`{}`)

```
USE {Your Database};
GO
--create an executor role
CREATE ROLE db_executor; 
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor;
GO
--Add AD group to roles.
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [{Your Domain}\{The AD Group}];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [{Your Domain}\{The AD Group}];
ALTER ROLE db_executor ADD MEMBER [{Your Domain}\{The AD Group}];
```